# F# and EF6 async

Tags: entity-framework, f#

I have a project structure where my data access code is in `C#` and a service project, which depends on the data access, is in `F#`. The data access project uses entity framework 6.1

In `F#` I cannot see any of the async methods for IQueryable? Do I have to add a reference to another project or something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe that they are in  the `System.Data.Entity` namespace, as C# Extension methods.